# Commission Junction API for Local (Daily) Deals

Tags: aggregator, commission-junction

Has anyone used Commission Junction's Product Catalog Search API for searching/fetching local deals? (BuyWithMe and KGBDeals post their deals to CJ)

There is a Yipit clone out there which uses this API. This clone was unable to categorize deals properly based on location. I was supposed to fix this issue. The problem I saw is: API's response does not contain location/city info. Therefore, deals cannot be categorized based on cities. This basically kills the purpose of local deals.

I am looking for advice from anyone who has done similar work using CJ API. May be I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneBigPlanet has an All-In-One API filled with all affiliate networks and daily deal providers for U.S & Canada

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a deal aggregator API for your site/blog, you may want to take a look at [this](http://sidebuy.com/api) one as well.

`SideBuy` has recently released its version 1 API which lets the user (like yourself) connect to its comprehensive set of daily deals using several parameters to fully customize the listings. I suggest you check it out and get in touch in SideBuy's site if you need further assistance.

Disclaimer: I work for `sidebuy.com`.